# R Shiny - Do I really need all these REACTIVE functions?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I've got an algorithm I've developed in R. Let's just say it's 5000 lines of code. Now I'm converting this to an R Shiny app, but the only way I can get the code to work is to put a REACTIVE function on almost *every* line of code. There has got to be an easier way!

Here is a highly simplified version. Here is the ui.R code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # application titles

  titlePanel("Calculate Next 3 Integers Above Specified Integer"),

  # sidebar panel

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(numericInput("int", "Enter integer", value="")),

  # main output

    mainPanel(textOutput("int1"),
          textOutput("int2"),
          textOutput("int3"))
  )))
```

And here is the server.R code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){

  int <- reactive({as.numeric(input$int)})

  int1 = reactive({int() + 1})
  int2 = reactive({int() + 2})
  int3 = reactive({int() + 3})

  output$int1 <- renderText(int1())
  output$int2 <- renderText(int2())
  output$int3 <- renderText(int3())

  })
```

You see where I define int1, int2, int3? Now suppose that I have many lines of code after this that use int1, int2, and int3. Every time I have R programming statements using int1, int2, or int3, I have to use a reactive function. Which in my current program means many dozens of times.

Is there not a way to put all of this code into some type of block that automatically applies REACTIVE to everything in the block? So every time it sees int1(), int2(), or int3() I don't need a separate REACTIVE function?

Comment: 5000 lines is significant - are you sure that you want to convert it to shiny as-is. I'd likely suggest structuring your code as a package and leveraging your algorithm as such. But having a shiny application that requires waiting for a long period of time while results are generated is likely not a fun user experience.

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite 5000 lines. :-) But it's a statistical algorithm that simulates various design elements for a set of clinical trials. So there are various inputs for study design, sample size restrictions, alternative numbers of dose arms, and a number of other inputs. The algorithm then quantifies probabilities for various outcomes based on thresholds that are also input by the user. So that's the basic idea. But there is a lot of processing, and then a number of outputs that are returned to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple reactive elements into one big reactive element and render that as an output. For example, in your example code, you can do something like:

```
output$new_output <- renderUI({
  str1 <- int1()
  str2 <- int2()
  str3 <- int3()
  HTML(paste(str1, str2, str3, sep = '<br/>'))
})
```

and render this in the UI using `htmlOutput("new_output")`. Similarly, if you have a dataframe or a table you can use `rbind` or something similar to combine elements into a bigger table etc.

Comment: OK, great. Thank you! I was certainly able to get that to work for the small example I have above, so I'll see if I can get this to work with the larger program I'm working on.